# How to set up entity (doctrine) for database view in Symfony 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's say I have a view table. And I want to get data from it to an entity. Can I (and how) create entity class to do that (no save operation needed)? I just want to display them.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is nothing special in querying a view — it's just a virtual table. Set the table of your entity this way and enjoy:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="your_view_table")
 */
class YourEntity {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: and then i get this error  "No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "BungaMata\CoreBundle\Entity\StyleCombined". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key"

Comment: @GusDeCooL, well, put an identifier then. ;)

Comment: Very, very bad practice. Call doctrine:schema:update... And table will be rewritten as simple table (not VIEW).

Comment: @user1954544, using an ORM to generate a schema is a bad practice.

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov Using and ORM to generate a schema is the practice recommended by Symfony. Also a lot of views don't have an identifier because of the nature of the query being ran.

Comment: so what the solution which will not create table instead of view? @ElnurAbdurrakhimov

Comment: @SergeVelikanov, if you let your ORM generate tables for you, you're in trouble. ;)

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov, so what's the best way to do it?

Comment: @SergeVelikanov, use a migration tool. Preferably a plain SQL one.

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov, but not the migration tool is part of the ORM (in Doctrine for example)?

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov yeah, what kind of migration tool are you thinking of? I'm using DoctrineMigrations and it seems pretty capable/straightforward (it uses SQL not DQL).

Comment: But how can I use it with the ORMPurger? It cannot delete the view.

Answer (score 49):

The accepted answer is correct, but I'd like to offer some additional suggestions that you might want to consider:

Mark your entity as read-only.

Make the constructor private so that only Doctrine can create instances.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(readOnly=true)
 * @ORM\Table(name="your_view_table")
 */
class YourEntity {
    private function __construct() {}
}
```

Comment: But how can I use it with the ORMPurger? It cannot delete the view.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to above anwers if you are using doctrine migrations for schema update the following configuration works perfectly.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(readOnly=true)
 * @ORM\Table(name="view_table_name")
 */
class YourEntity {
    private function __construct() {}
}
```

Till here is te same as above answers. Here you need to configure doctrine not to bind schemas;

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        schema_filter: ~^(?!view_)~
```

The above filter definition filters all 'view_' prefixed tables as well as views an could be extended using regex. Just make sure you have named your views with 'view_' prefix.

But doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql still shows the views, I hope they will integrate the same filter to schema update too.

I hope this solution would help some others.

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#manual-tables

Comment: This does not work with doctrine 2.4 at least. The schema update tries to create a table.

Comment: `console d:s:u` still wants to create the table with `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle:2.1.2` but it's working fine with the migrations so that's ok for me

Comment: This seems to work with Doctrine 3+. Solution is also referenced in symfony docs: https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html#manual-tables

Answer (score 22):

Both the previous answers are correct, but if you use the doctrine migration tool and do a `schema:update` it will fail...

So, in addition to marking the entity as read only and making the constructor private (explained in Ian Phillips answer):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(readOnly=true)
 * @ORM\Table(name="your_view_table")
 */
class YourEntity {
    private function __construct() {}
}
```

You would need to set the schema tool to ignore the entity when doing a schema:update...

In order to do that you just need to create this command in your bundle, and set yout entity in the ignoredEntity list:

src/Acme/CoreBundle/Command/DoctrineUpdateCommand.php:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\CoreBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;

class DoctrineUpdateCommand extends \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand {

  protected $ignoredEntities = array(
      'Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\EntityToIgnore'
  );

  protected function executeSchemaCommand(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output, SchemaTool $schemaTool, array $metadatas) {

    /** @var $metadata \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata[] */
    $newMetadatas = array();
    foreach ($metadatas as $metadata) {
      if (!in_array($metadata->getName(), $this->ignoredEntities)) {
        array_push($newMetadatas, $metadata);
      }
    }

    parent::executeSchemaCommand($input, $output, $schemaTool, $newMetadatas);
  }

}
```

(credit to Alexandru Trandafir Catalin: obtained from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25948910/1442457)

BTW, this is the only way I found to work with views from doctrine... I know it is a workaround... If there is a better way I am open or suggestions)

Comment: but this works only when update is called, validate shows that failed.

Comment: You are right Marcus, I've just tried that and it fails... I guess that if you use validation you should add the entity to an exclusion list for validation (similar to what I did with update). It is possible but excluding the entity from updates is a hack already, I think symfony should implement some built-in functionality for views ...

Comment: Can't you create the view in an seperate Entity Manager? This will solve the "schema:update" problem I think.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to above answer, You must have a naming Strategy of your view' entities and the virtual tables, for example: view_your_table, and then you must add the following code to the doctrine.yaml, to disable creating new migration file to the view:
`schema_filter: ~^(?!view_)~`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to above answer, I have mixed some of your example code to extend the DoctrineUpdateCommand

This is my DoctrineUpdateCommand:

```
class DoctrineUpdateCommand extends UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand{
   protected function executeSchemaCommand(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output, SchemaTool $schemaTool, array $metadatas) {
      $container = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer();  

     $filterExpr = $container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->getFilterSchemaAssetsExpression();
     $emptyFilterExpression = empty($filterExpr);

     /** @var $newMetadatas \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata */
     $newMetadatas = array();

     foreach ($metadatas as $metadata) {
        if(($emptyFilterExpression||preg_match($filterExpr, $metadata->getTableName()))){
            array_push($newMetadatas, $metadata);
        }        
     }

     parent::executeSchemaCommand($input, $output, $schemaTool, $newMetadatas);
 }
}
```

Thanks for the right way

Answer (score 1):

I spend a day on that due to the necessity to introduce a view in my database on the Zend implementation.

As all previously said, you should create an entity, and this entity must have `Id()` annotation:

```php
/**
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table(name="your_view")
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity(readOnly=true)
 */
class YourViewEntity
{
    /**
     * @var SomeEntityInterface
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id()
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OneToOne(targetEntity="SomeMainEntity", fetch="LAZY")
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn(nullable=false, referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $some;

    /**
     * @var AnotherEntityInterface
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AnotherEntity", fetch="LAZY")
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn(nullable=false, referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $another;

    // Make the constructor private so that only Doctrine can create instances.
    private function __construct() {}
}
```

also with private constructor as described in [Ian Phillips answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982478/4615331). Yet this does not prevent `orm:schema-tool:update` to create a table based on new entity, trying to override our view... Despite the fact that using `orm:schema-tool:update` should be avoided on production in favor of migration scripts, for development purposes this is extremely useful.

As `schema_filter: ~^(?!view_)~` is both seem to not working, also deprecated, I managed to find a trick on [Kamil Adryjanek page](http://kamiladryjanek.com/ignore-entity-or-table-when-running-doctrine2-schema-update-command/) that presents option to add an `EventListener` or `Subscriber` to entity manager, that will prevent creating table for us. Mine implementation below:

```php
class SkipAutogenerateTableSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public const CONFIG_KEY = "skip_autogenerate_entities";

    private $ignoredEntities = [];

    public function __construct($config)
    {
        if (array_key_exists(self::CONFIG_KEY, $config)) {
            $this->ignoredEntities = (array) $config[self::CONFIG_KEY];
        }
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            ToolEvents::postGenerateSchema
        ];
    }

    public function postGenerateSchema(GenerateSchemaEventArgs $args)
    {
        $schema = $args->getSchema();
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();

        $ignoredTables = [];
        foreach ($this->ignoredEntities as $entityName) {
            $ignoredTables[] = $em->getClassMetadata($entityName)->getTableName();
        }

        foreach ($schema->getTables() as $table) {

            if (in_array($table->getName(), $ignoredTables)) {
                $schema->dropTable($table->getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this solves problem not only for `orm:schema-tool`, but also for `migrations:diff` of `doctrine/migrations` module.