# Doctrine 2 - Generate entities with views from database

Tags: database, view, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to generate a view from database with Doctrine 2?

I explain:

My db contains some views I want use, but I don't know how generate these views.

In my case, I have two tables and one view, the view selects a few columns in each table and I just want THIS view in the folder "Entity" of the project.

Comment: Do you mean _view_ in the context of [Model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)?

Comment: Nope i mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL) , that type of view. 
For example, i have a database (toto) with two tables (tata et titi) and a view (viewTataTiti) who select results in this two tables.

Comment: I seen this too : http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/using-views-with-doctrine.html 
But my "view" is already in my database ... i just want to recuperate this view.

Answer (score 8):

Database views are <s>not</s> **currently** supported by Doctrine 2, but it can potentially perform very badly. Try it yourself mapping the view as an entity and mark it as a @readOnly entity.

Comment: Where did you see that ?

Comment: Try it yourself. Doctrine2 schema tool will not recognize the view as table, because it is a state.

Comment: I will try tomorrow at work.

Look the last point, 26.2.1, it's hope maybe ...
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html

Comment: Please,you have examples ?

Comment: @manix Why did you change your answer about support from **not** to **is**? [See stof's comment](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/pull/184)

Comment: @Taylan, just a note: readonly property has no relation with views, because the views naturally is just for reading purposes. And yes, I do; I changed from "not" to "is" because is completely valid working with views in Doctrine.

Comment: @manix, what I mean is you can use views with doctrine but it is not officially supported. Also as far as i can see for readOnly entities Doctrine ORM still allows to insert/delete, but not updating them. So what would happen if someone were to try to insert/delete rows on an entity mapped to a view? I haven't tried but I'm assuming it will give an error. Maybe you can add a warning to your answer about this.

Comment: @Taylan, I get your point, but lets put the things in practices.. You can not insert records into a view using doctrine neither directly from database, that is not possible, a view internally is just a SELECT statement. Indeed, if you plan insert records using a view you are not understanding the concept of view. In the other hand, lets have a "employees" table, and in your application want to display a list of birthdays, so create a view that calculates the next 20 birthdays called "birthdates". From doctrine you can use that view without problems. That is the main purpose of mapping a view.

Comment: Actually, views in different rdms MAY be updatable or insertable (i.e. they are not always read only). For mysql, for instance: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html . Since the criteria of different rdms to make a view updatable or not are highly technical (and dependent), I think Doctrine may have chosen to send queries anyway and let the database reject the queries...

Comment: @VincentPazeller, `I think Doctrine may have chosen to send queries anyway and let the database reject the queries...`. Totally agreed

Answer (score 0):

For people who are interested by the answer :

I based my answer on this :
[How to set up entity (doctrine) for database view in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377671/how-to-set-up-entity-doctrine-for-database-view-in-symfony-2)

For example , if you have a view "A" with column "Id" and "Name" :

At src/Name/YourBundle/Resources/config/doctrine, create "A.orm.yml" with attributs like :

```
Name\YourBundle\Entity\A:
type: entity
table: A
fields:
    id:
        id: true
        type: integer
        unsigned: false
        nullable: false
        column: id
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
    name:
        type: string
        length: 35
        fixed: false
        nullable: true
        column: name
```

After that, create your A.php in Name/YourBundle/Entity/A :

```
namespace Name\YourBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="A")
 */
class A {

    /**
    * @Id @Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

And ... you can call your view with your controller.

Comment: And this works for you? I'm having issues trying to get this working see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28141515/how-to-map-and-use-a-db-view-from-doctrine2

Comment: This answer is completely wrong, the OP is asking something different.