# Create table in symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I want to create a table of objects in Symfony2 from different entities.
I have two entities: entity user and account. I have to retrieve the information from these two entities and build a table that contains information from both table and return the table result as a response and send it in an email.

for example, I have tow entity in database: table user and table account,

In my controller, I want to get the data from two table and fuse the data into new table (not in database), just multidimensional table. 
getting the data from two table is easy, but how I can't create an array of object in symfony that contains all data retrieved

```
 listsofaccounts=$em->getRepository('....:Account')->getAllAccount()

 listsofuser=$em->getRepository('..:user')->getAllusers()
```

My question, is how to put the two result into new object `$tableResults`  which contains all information from the `listsofaccounts` and `listsofusers`

```
$tableResult=$listofAccounts+$lissofusers
```

Comment: Is a relation between user and account entities ?

Comment: no relation, getting information done, but I need to create a table result which contain information from the two table, just how use array to create multidimensionnel table

Comment: He is probably trying to say he wants to create a table view. Unfortunately, that's not possible with Doctrine. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499176/doctrine-2-generate-entities-with-views-from-database

Comment: I don't want to use shema update, just put the results into a table

Comment: Your question is missing some information, what is the desired result? What should $tableResults specifically look like?

Comment: $resultTable: contains a set of row from $listsofaccounts and $listsofuser

Comment: A concrete example would help.  Assuming User1, User2 & User3, and Acct1, Acct2, Acct3, what would the result look like?

Comment: @MajdiTaleb you should make the difference between "table", which is used to talk about part of a database, and "array", which is what I think you want here.

Comment: yes exactly, I found a solution , I will use the same solution in php

Comment: Please post your solution when it worked. It will clearify what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand you right, but my suggestion would be for you to use the array_merge() function, like this :

```
$tableResult = array_merge($listofAccounts, $listofusers);
```

array_merge() accepts arrays as parameters, which is what should be returned by a "getAll...()" method.

Hope this helps.