# Symfony2, Doctrine2, MySql, view tables

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Simple question, is there support for view-tables in doctrine2? I found that it can 'read' current schema http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html But can it create new view-tables like others entity\tables ?

It can solve a lot of issues.

Comment: Apparently yes... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377671/how-to-set-up-entity-doctrine-for-database-view-in-symfony-2

Comment: No, there is simple description of it. If I call doctrine:schema:update I will broke this view. I need full description of it (i mean view) like base entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to define views in mappers I think you can't do this
If you want simply use views to read data from them I think you can do it. Simply define views fields in mapper as for general tables

Comment: Yeah seems it's imposible to do, because any call on doctrine update call will borke it. I talked to another developers and we decide that doctrine cannot handle view tables. :(

Answer (score 2):

The technique I used is to create an entity based on the view :

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

Verify the following parameters in the created entity annotations :
    
    `/**
     * @ORM\Table(name="table_name")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TableNameRepository")
    */`

Then create a new table with a sql command :

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Name 
AS 
SELECT v.field1,v.field2,v.field3,w.field4 
FROM view1 v,view2 w 
WHERE v.id=w.id;
```

To add a doctrine like primary key to your view, use this statement :

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

Or you can specify the new table name with Doctrine and create it with a :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

followed by a

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Then use your entity in the controller, as simple as that.

Comment: app/console should be replaced with bin/console