# How to use the flag readOnly in Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, annotations, entity

A Doctrine [entity](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-entity) can have the flag `readOnly`.

How should the flag `readOnly` be used?

```
/** @Entity(readOnly) */ <-- like this?
/** @Entity(readOnly=true) */ <-- or like this?
class User
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982478/488666) and [this issue](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/issues/194), the latter is the way to go:

```
/** @Entity(readOnly=true) */
```