# easiest way to fetch query to array of object in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

[View](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)) in database I mean :

```
create view `vMaketType` as select * from MaketType
```

I have a **[view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL))** in **database**, but because of doctrine cant support it now, i using query, and fetch it one by one :

```
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $con = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
        $stmt = $con->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM vMaketType');
        $domain = [];
        //I must fetch it and set it one by one
        foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row){
           $obj = new vMaketType();
           $obj->setId($row["Id"]);
           $obj->setName($row["Name"]);
           $obj->setAmount($row["Amount"]);
           array_push($domain, $obj);
        }
```

for me this is really takes too much time to code one by one.

vMaketType is a **custom entity** I created to send data from controller to [Twig]view.

is there any easier way to fetch to array of object vMaketType?

because I have a view with 24 fields, I wish there is easier way for it.

Comment: Why don't you just use MarketType (I'm assuming that's your entity with mapping information)?

Comment: He says it doesn't work with sql views, but I don't see why: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377671/how-to-set-up-entity-doctrine-for-database-view-in-symfony-2

Comment: I use ORM generate schema

Comment: So what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try with the serializer:

```
$obj = $this->get('serializer')->deserialize($row, 'Namespace\MaketType', 'array');
```

Code not tested, tweaks may be done, [see the related doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-an-object).

Comment: I've been read it, but it cant  works for view, that's why I used handcoded query. :) you should read my explanation first, or cmiiw if there is any way orm doctrine support view

Comment: cmon, bro, you dont understand what i ask