# How add read-only property to doctrine entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

my entity:

```
class MyEntity {

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hash", type="string", length=128, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $hash;

}
```

hash - is auto generate column by database. When i try create new record in db i getting

> null value in column "hash" violates not-null constraint

is there an opportunity to make hash read-only? or disable for insert?

Comment: You can mark an entity as read-only. Example https://stackoverflow.com/a/34982478/2210147

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `insertable` and `updatable` attributes with [the @Column annotation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_column) to mark the property as read-only:

```
class MyEntity {

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hash", type="string", insertable=false, updatable=false, length=128, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $hash;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the value at the entity constructor and don't create a setter. That will make your property read only from outside of the entity.