# How to validate a not updatable column with symfony/validator?

Tags: php, symfony, validation, doctrine, phpunit

I have a column that it's a DateTimeImmutable that save when the user has joined the platform. I'm making the phpunit test and i would like to validate that the colum can't be updated. I would like to detect the error before arriving to the SQL error (error when trying to update column).

```
 #[ORM\Column(updatable: false)]
    #[Assert\Type(
        type: 'object',
        message: 'The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}.'
    )]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $joinedAt = null;
```

I've tried to update the entity column and then call the $manager->persist($entity) to see if there is an error at that time, but nothing happen.

```
  public function testInvalidJoinedAt(): void
    {
        $manager = static::getContainer()->get(EntityManagerInterface::class);

        // User joinedAt cannot be updated
        $now = new DateTimeImmutable();
        $existingUser = $this->getRepository(UserRepository::class)->find(0);
        $existingUser->setJoinedAt($now);

        try {
            $manager->persist($existingUser);
        } catch (\Throwable $err) {
            $this->assertEquals('???', $err->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

An assert type like "#[Assert\NotUpdatable]" would be the perfect solution but there isn't something like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How add read-only property to doctrine entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669085/how-add-read-only-property-to-doctrine-entity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony Validator doesn't have a built-in constraint like #[Assert\NotUpdatable] to handle this specific use case. However, you can create a custom validation constraint to achieve the desired functionality. Here's how you can do it:

1. Create a custom validation constraint class:
   Create a new constraint class that will be responsible for checking whether the joinedAt property is being updated.

```
// src/Validator/Constraints/NotUpdatable.php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class NotUpdatable extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The "{{ field }}" field cannot be updated.';
}
```

2. Create a custom validator class:
   Next, create a custom validator class that will perform the validation.

```
// src/Validator/Constraints/NotUpdatableValidator.php

namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class NotUpdatableValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $entity = $this->context->getObject();

        // Check if the entity is managed by Doctrine (already in the database)
        if ($this->doctrine->getManager()->contains($entity)) {
            $originalEntity = $this->doctrine->getManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($entity);

            // Compare the original joinedAt value with the new one
            if ($originalEntity['joinedAt'] !== $value) {
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                    ->setParameter('{{ field }}', $this->context->getPropertyName())
                    ->addViolation();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Apply the custom constraint to your entity property:
   Now, apply the custom NotUpdatable constraint to the joinedAt property in your entity class:

```
// src/Entity/User.php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Validator\Constraints as CustomAssert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(updatable: false)
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type='object',
     *     message='The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}.'
     * )
     * @CustomAssert\NotUpdatable
     */
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $joinedAt = null;

    // ...
}
```

4. Update your test to trigger the validation:
   Finally, you can update your PHPUnit test to trigger the validation and ensure that the joinedAt property cannot be updated:

```
public function testInvalidJoinedAt(): void
{
    $manager = static::getContainer()->get(EntityManagerInterface::class);

    // User joinedAt cannot be updated
    $now = new DateTimeImmutable();
    $existingUser = $this->getRepository(UserRepository::class)->find(0);
    $existingUser->setJoinedAt($now);

    $validator = static::getContainer()->get('validator');
    $violations = $validator->validate($existingUser);

    $this->assertCount(1, $violations);
    $this->assertEquals('The "joinedAt" field cannot be updated.', $violations[0]->getMessage());
}
```

This test will ensure that the joinedAt property cannot be updated, and it will validate the custom constraint you've created. If the constraint is violated, it will catch the violation, and you can assert the error message as shown above.

Comment: I had to modify the code a little. I don't know why but ->getManager()->contains($entity) and ->getManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($entity) do not work correctly. However, the logic is clearly understood and I have managed to adapt it.

Comment: OK what errors do you have?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own custom validator checkout the doc here [enter link description here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)
in your src/Validator/Constraints add the files
1)

```
class fileName extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Error Message Goes here for not modifd property';
}
```

2. 

```
 class FileName extends ConstraintValidator
 {
     public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
     {
         if ($value !== null) {
         $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)->addViolation();
     }
   }
 }
```

3. you can add your custom validator to your entity asserts

   ```
   /**
     * @ORM\Column(updatable=false)
     * @customValidator\validatorName
     */
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $joinedAt = null;
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Doctrine does not validate Symfony Validation attributes. You must validate the entity with the Symfony Validator before saving it.

With a custom validator you need to know if it is an insert or an update, because the Symfony validator does not know if you are doing an insert or an update. Such could create such a custom validator. But it is a bigger effort.

I would solve it based on your method `testInvalidJoinedAt()` so you do not have to validate.

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;

class Entity
{
    #[Column(updatable: false)]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $joinedAt = null;

    public function getJoinedAt(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->joinedAt;
    }

    public function setJoinedAt(?\DateTimeImmutable $joinedAt): void
    {
        if (!$this->joinedAt instanceof \DateTimeImmutable) {
            $this->joinedAt = $joinedAt;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example UnitTest**

```php
class EntityTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testNewEntity() {
        $dateTime = new DateTimeImmutable();
        $entity = new Entity();
        $entity->setJoinedAt($dateTime);
        $this->assertEquals($dateTime, $entity->getJoinedAt());
    }

    public function testEntityFromDatabase() {
        // Mock entity from database
        $dateTime = new DateTimeImmutable();
        $dateTime->setDate(2022, 9, 17)->setTime(19, 31, 41);
        $entityFromDatabase = new Entity();
        $entityFromDatabase->setJoinedAt($dateTime);

        // Set joinedAt update
        $entityFromDatabase->setJoinedAt(
            (new DateTimeImmutable())->setDate(2023, 10, 19)->setTime(8, 11, 15)
        );

        $this->assertEquals($dateTime, $entityFromDatabase->getJoinedAt());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be valid but it's not exactly what i was searching. Thanks for the answer !